# Do you know some tools can help to create fake data which was used in unit test of asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I was using aps.net mvc unit test, and want to create fake data instead of using real database connection, but the Linq query code and real database was huge and complicated, create fake data in unit test which can mimic real database was a huge job! Who knows some tools can help me to create fake data and mimic real database? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the Isolator, it has the ability to mock almost everything including asp.net MVC, I think it will fit your needs.
You can examine the ASP.NET MVC mocking [here](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fmockingaspdotnetmvc.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Object Hydrator](http://objecthydrator.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

Comment: This project can just generate some limit kind of data, which was different form my using database, I want a tool to decrease the size of database and create mimic data to cover most tables of database.